# How deep was Coruscant's surface buried?

Tags: star-wars, video-games, planets

I knew that Coruscant's undercity received no light, but I didn't realize how big it was. In the trailer for the upcoming game *[Star Wars 1313](http://www.lucasarts.com/games/1313/index.html)*, a panoramic shot of level 1313 is shown:

[image]

You can easily see large skyscrapers in the level, so it's not like each level is one story tall. According to Wookieepedia,

> Level 1313, one thousand three hundred and thirteen levels from Coruscant's core, was a ruthless criminal underground situated deep below the surface of Coruscant.

So the number corresponds to how many *levels* above the planet's surface it was, not feet or meters or anything. My question is, how deep (quantifiable in feet, meters, or miles) was the actual surface of Coruscant buried?

Comment: Wookiepedia also states that the oceans were drained, further complicating this question. The only reference I've seen was "Several Kilometers".

Comment: Right. And of course the Manarai Mountains actually were visible above the cityscape. I guess I'm looking for the deepest point or the average point they were above ground (above sea level). Either would work. Alternatively, the height of the Manarai Mtns (ASL) would work

Comment: @SSumner - I think its about 8 minutes deep. Now if you will excuse me I am going to try and beat Han's time of 11 parsecs on the Kessel Run.

Comment: On a serious note I think it is kept deliberately oblique.  A building may be 1000 levels but it is built on a building which is built on another building, etc. there seems to be no limit to the depths of Coruscant

Comment: @Chad-you are aware that that was not his *time*, right? He actually cut *distance* off the Kessel Run

Comment: @SSumner: Yes, as explained later after people made a fuss and some author wrote that. But one may argue that, originally, Lucas was trying to make Han sound like a pompous ass on purpose.

Comment: Most likely. Another example of LucasPhysics and retconning

Comment: Your quote seems to imply that it's not 1313 "levels above the planets surface" (which would be in the atmosphere) but 1313 levels above the core. So if you started on the surface, travelling towards 1313, the numbers would start to *decrease*. If we knew which level the surface is and the average height per level, we could calculate the depth of level 1 (or 0).

Comment: @bitmask - that is certainly possible - I hadn't thought of that. But I have no clue how tall a level is.

Also, we don't know that level 1313 is below the surface. If your hypothesis is correct (which it does seem to follow from the quote), then the surface would be on some level # > 0. Maybe 1313 is below or above the surface.

Comment: @SSumner: I don't follow; How can a level without sunlight and with a ceiling be above the surface? The surface level would have to be > 1313, according to the quote you provide.

Comment: No...over the years, buildings were built upon other buildings, and over centuries, the lower levels became completely encased without sunlight.

"The bottom fifty levels that made up the underworld were buried under levels of duracrete and buildings."

Comment: Is explanation given to how buildings are built on top of others and are somehow stable?

Comment: @Charlie - from all that I read, it never sounded like buildings on top of just buildings

Comment: In the picture, there is clearly a "ceiling" to the level. Presumably once the level had been built up, they added a ceiling which was structurally strong enough to build further levels on. Not buildings on top of other buildings, but buildings on top of other levels.

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer as I can't add much, but in the Clone Wars, Season 5, Episodes 17/1819/20 Ashoka ends up in level 1325, in a disused weapons warehouse.   This series is considered canon, and further analysis could help answer the question.  And it is a long way down.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It looks like Darth Mikey struck again.

As [per the latest news](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2013/04/end-of-an-era-disney-shuts-down-internal-game-development-at-lucasarts/), LucasArts game development is 100% cancelled (as in, entire development team was fired by Disney) and all in-house game development was stopped post-merger; including **cancellation of "1313"**

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I've seen a bunch of references to 1-2 miles tall buildings. I could never find the actual canon reference for that, however.

---

However, there seems to be conflicting info in the new canon.

As per 2 different articles about 1313 game ([here](https://www.complex.com/video-games/2012/06/star-wars-1313-will-be-unlike-any-star-wars-game-youve-ever-played) and [here](https://www.heraldsun.com.au/technology/gaming/e3-2012-star-wars-1313/story-fn6rvxri-1226386205031)) there are 5000 total levels.

Since each level must be at LEAST 2 meters tall, and likely is 3+ (considering modern skyscrapers), that nets us at least 10-15km in depth.

Comment: What about the levels just for Jawas, Ewoks and astro-droids?

Comment: @Pureferret - why would they bother building for non-humans?

Comment: 5000 total levels sounds like a really long game.

Comment: @Charlie - that's referring to the total levels on *Coruscant*, not the game

Comment: *each* level must be 2 meters tall, but obviously 1313 is taller than that, since it contains skyscrapers *inside* the level. So while 10-15km is the bare minimum, it seems an extremely low estimate, since I would assume there are other levels like 1313 that are hundreds or thousands of feet tall, even if they are not the majority.
Accepting this answer because there doesn't appear to be any other canon specifying further details.

Comment: @SSumner - Is there a firm proof that those skyscrapers are entirely in level 1313, as opposed to one floor of them, and the rest being different levels? Your Q says "You can easily see large skyscrapers in the level", but that's possibly just a view from a window, NOT "what you see is the level". Can't be sure without lots more details

Comment: @SSumner - remember that canonicity of games is "questionable". If a fact from the game contradicts other facts from canon, the former is not canonical. Especially when that fact is a mere visual as opposed to a script.

Comment: @DVK - no, there is not. But the view appears immediately after descending into the planet, and entering Level 1313. Therefore, I *assume* that the skyscrapers are part of level 1313, but you're right, I can't be sure.

But references in canon have established that entire levels were built up, and then over the centuries, other levels were built on top of them. If levels were simply floors in a skyscraper, I can't imagine this statement being accurate.

Comment: I had already heard about the cancellation, but thanks for the update. Sad :(

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer as I can't add much, but in the Clone Wars, Season 5, Episodes 17/1819/20 Ashoka ends up in level 1325, in a disused weapons warehouse.   This series is considered canon, and further analysis could help answer the question.  And it is a long way down.

Comment: @PeterM - seems like a pretty good asnwer to me, personally

Comment: Its a good answer for the levels, but not for the depth - which is what the OP wanted.  Even with a canon number of levels the depth is still speculation, especially as 1315 was a good 10 or 15 stories tall in itself.